# handoutWithNotes Missing \begin{document} error

Tags: beamer, handout

The code below returns a `Missing \begin{document}` error, and I don't know why.

Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
sample text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.3.13)  13 MAR 2017 19:59
entering extended mode
**./mwe.tex
(mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamer.cls"
Document Class: beamer 2017/01/23 v3.41 A class for typesetting presentations
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count79
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemodes.sty"
\beamer@tempbox=\box26
\beamer@tempcount=\count80
\c@beamerpauses=\count81

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasedecode.sty"
\beamer@slideinframe=\count82
\beamer@minimum=\count83
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box27
\beamer@modecount=\count84
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
\headheight=\dimen102
\headdp=\dimen103
\footheight=\dimen104
\sidebarheight=\dimen105
\beamer@tempdim=\dimen106
\beamer@finalheight=\dimen107
\beamer@animht=\dimen108
\beamer@animdp=\dimen109
\beamer@animwd=\dimen110
\beamer@leftmargin=\dimen111
\beamer@rightmargin=\dimen112
\beamer@leftsidebar=\dimen113
\beamer@rightsidebar=\dimen114
\beamer@boxsize=\dimen115
\beamer@vboxoffset=\dimen116
\beamer@descdefault=\dimen117
\beamer@descriptionwidth=\dimen118
\beamer@lastskip=\skip41
\beamer@areabox=\box28
\beamer@animcurrent=\box29
\beamer@animshowbox=\box30
\beamer@sectionbox=\box31
\beamer@logobox=\box32
\beamer@linebox=\box33
\beamer@sectioncount=\count85
\beamer@subsubsectionmax=\count86
\beamer@subsectionmax=\count87
\beamer@sectionmax=\count88
\beamer@totalheads=\count89
\beamer@headcounter=\count90
\beamer@partstartpage=\count91
\beamer@sectionstartpage=\count92
\beamer@subsectionstartpage=\count93
\beamer@animationtempa=\count94
\beamer@animationtempb=\count95
\beamer@xpos=\count96
\beamer@ypos=\count97
\beamer@showpartnumber=\count98
\beamer@currentsubsection=\count99
\beamer@coveringdepth=\count100
\beamer@sectionadjust=\count101
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\count102

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip42
\beamer@paperheight=\skip43

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count103
\Gm@cntv=\count104
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count105
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen119
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen120
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen121
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen122
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen123
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen124
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen125
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen126
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count106
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen127
\Gin@req@width=\dimen128
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen129
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen130

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box34
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen131
\pgf@y=\dimen132
\pgf@xa=\dimen133
\pgf@ya=\dimen134
\pgf@xb=\dimen135
\pgf@yb=\dimen136
\pgf@xc=\dimen137
\pgf@yc=\dimen138
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count107
\c@pgf@countb=\count108
\c@pgf@countc=\count109
\c@pgf@countd=\count110
\t@pgf@toka=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks22
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def"
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count111
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count112
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen139
\pgfmath@count=\count113
\pgfmath@box=\box35
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count114
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen140
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen141
\pgf@picminy=\dimen142
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen143
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen144
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen145
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen146
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen147
\pgf@xx=\dimen148
\pgf@xy=\dimen149
\pgf@yx=\dimen150
\pgf@yy=\dimen151
\pgf@zx=\dimen152
\pgf@zy=\dimen153
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen154
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen155
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen156
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen157
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box36
\pgf@hbox=\box37
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box38
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count115
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen158
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen159
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen160
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen161
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen162
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen163
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count116
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box39
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\xxcolor.sty"
Package: xxcolor 2003/10/24 ver 0.1
\XC@nummixins=\count117
\XC@countmixins=\count118
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifvtex' (already loaded).
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `atbegshi' (already loaded).
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen164
\Hy@linkcounter=\count119
\Hy@pagecounter=\count120

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count121

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4362.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 4362.
Package hyperref Info: Option `implicit' set `false' on input line 4362.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4486.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4491.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4494.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4501.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4506.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode OFF; no redefinition of LaTeX internals.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4735.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count122

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5088.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen165
\Fld@menulength=\count123
\Field@Width=\dimen166
\Fld@charsize=\dimen167
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6342.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6350.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6357.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6372.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6412.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6416.
\Hy@abspage=\count124


Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count125
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count126

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaserequires.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecompatibility.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasefont.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks26
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sansmathaccent\sansmathaccent.sty"
Package: sansmathaccent 2013/03/28

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty"
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetranslator.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\translator\translator.sty"
Package: translator 2010/06/12 ver 1.10

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\translator\translator-language-m
appings.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemisc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetwoscreens.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoverlay.sty"
\beamer@argscount=\count127
\beamer@lastskipcover=\skip44
\beamer@trivlistdepth=\count128
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetitle.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasesection.sty"
\c@lecture=\count129
\c@part=\count130
\c@section=\count131
\c@subsection=\count132
\c@subsubsection=\count133
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframe.sty"
\beamer@framebox=\box40
\beamer@frametitlebox=\box41
\beamer@zoombox=\box42
\beamer@zoomcount=\count134
\beamer@zoomframecount=\count135
\beamer@frametextheight=\dimen168
\c@subsectionslide=\count136
\beamer@frametopskip=\skip45
\beamer@framebottomskip=\skip46
\beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\skip47
\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\skip48
\beamer@envbody=\toks27
\framewidth=\dimen169
\c@framenumber=\count137
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseverbatim.sty"
\beamer@verbatimfileout=\write4
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframesize.sty"
\beamer@splitbox=\box43
\beamer@autobreakcount=\count138
\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\dimen170
\beamer@frametitletoks=\toks28
\beamer@framesubtitletoks=\toks29
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframecomponents.sty"
\beamer@footins=\box44
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecolor.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenotes.sty"
\beamer@frameboxcopy=\box45
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetoc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetemplates.sty"
\beamer@sbttoks=\toks30

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseboxes.sty"
\bmb@box=\box46
\bmb@colorbox=\box47
\bmb@boxshadow=\box48
\bmb@boxshadowball=\box49
\bmb@boxshadowballlarge=\box50
\bmb@temp=\dimen171
\bmb@dima=\dimen172
\bmb@dimb=\dimen173
\bmb@prevheight=\dimen174
)
\beamer@blockheadheight=\dimen175
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaselocalstructure.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\enumerate.sty"
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks31
)
\c@figure=\count139
\c@table=\count140
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenavigation.sty"
\beamer@section@min@dim=\dimen176
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetheorems.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip51

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks32
\ex@=\dimen177
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen178
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count141
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count142
\leftroot@=\count143
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count144
\DOTSCASE@=\count145
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
\big@size=\dimen179
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count146
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count147
\dotsspace@=\muskip11
\c@parentequation=\count148
\dspbrk@lvl=\count149
\tag@help=\toks33
\row@=\count150
\column@=\count151
\maxfields@=\count152
\andhelp@=\toks34
\eqnshift@=\dimen180
\alignsep@=\dimen181
\tagshift@=\dimen182
\tagwidth@=\dimen183
\totwidth@=\dimen184
\lineht@=\dimen185
\@envbody=\toks35
\multlinegap=\skip52
\multlinetaggap=\skip53
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks36
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty"
Package: amsthm 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
\thm@style=\toks37
\thm@bodyfont=\toks38
\thm@headfont=\toks39
\thm@notefont=\toks40
\thm@headpunct=\toks41
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks42
)
\c@theorem=\count153
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasethemes.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\themes\theme\beamerthemedefault.
sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\themes\font\beamerfontthemedefau
lt.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\themes\color\beamercolorthemedef
ault.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\themes\inner\beamerinnerthemedef
ault.sty"
\beamer@dima=\dimen186
\beamer@dimb=\dimen187
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\themes\outer\beamerouterthemedef
ault.sty"))) (handoutWithNotes.sty

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                        
l.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Where is `handoutWithNotes` from?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. GitHub: https://github.com/gdiepen/latexbeamer-handoutWithNotes

Comment: @Bobyandbob: Thanks, but this is a information that the O.P. should add, not we ;-)

Comment: @Bobyandbob: No. It was meant as a hint to the O.P. ...

Comment: Well, using the link from @Bobyandbob I downloaded  the `.sty` file and the document compiled without errors

Comment: is it line 1 showing weird characters before `\documentclass` in which case you have a BOM character there which you should remove.

Comment: Is `Missing \begin{document}` the first error in your log file? That said, your MWE compiles fine for me too.

Comment: Hi All -- To compound my problems, I don't know how to read log files.  That said, the log file does not mention this error at all.  I do appreciate everyone's efforts. Also, sorry for not linking to handoutWithNotes.sty, and no, David, no weird characters. However I don't know what a BOM character is...

Comment: @dcalvis Can you post the .log file of the MWE in your question? You should find it in the same folder as your .tex file. It has the same name and ends with `.log`.

Comment: samcarter -- I would be happy to do so.  I don't see a way at this site to post an attachment.  So I am simply going to append it to my original code.  This does not seem like the right way to do it, so apologies in advance. Thanks.

Comment: Probably some lines of your log files got lost. It should show the error message at its end. Maybe you could post the last 10+ lines instead of the whole file?

Comment: @dcalvis Is there more of the log file?

Comment: Thanks for the edits!  I am all thumbs with this web site, obviously.  No, @Jurgen and @samcarter, I checked and this is it. The only thing I think of to add is the last few lines of my console output, below.  Again so many thanks to all.

`! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 <
     !DOCTYPE html>
?`

Comment: @dcalvis Just a guess, but can you try to update your latex distribution?

Comment: Hello @samcarter -- The only thing I know to do along this line is to run the MikTeX update wizard.  Did so, all ran smoothly, but the error persists.  Did I in fact update my latex distribution? Thanks.

Comment: @dcalvis Can you check you log file again? Which version of `beamer` do you have now?

Comment: Thanks @samcarter I just updated the log file above; looks as though I am current now.

Comment: @dcalvis Looks good. As far as I can see, you're now using exactly the same package versions as I do. Last idea: are you using the current version of https://github.com/gdiepen/latexbeamer-handoutWithNotes

Comment: Why is `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your comment, but not in what you pasted above?

Comment: Thanks @Teepeemm -- This log file is an update from the original.  I updated my MikTeX at samcarter's kind suggestion, and this is now what I get.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for your "last idea".  Answer would have to be yes, since I just discovered `handoutWithNotes` and the latest version seems to be almost a year old.

Comment: @dcalvis Sorry, then I am afraid, I am out of ideas what might be the source of the error. I wish you good luck with your question!